# Change CSS color of text based on PHP variable

Tags: php, css

I have been searching for days now and I have tried countless times but all the examples I have tried are not working. I have a field that pulls a variable and I want to change the color of the text based on the selection of that variable. So if the variable is set to Undecided I want the text to change to red but if any other option is selected I want it to remain black. This is the line of code on the template for the page that pulls the variable which is currently working correctly:

```
<p id="orient" style="color:#<?php echo $style; ?> "><strong>Orientation: <?php echo get_field('orientation',get_the_ID()); ?></strong></p>
```

I then tried a bunch of ways but this is what I am currently trying to get to work:

```
var ori = "<?php echo get_field('orientation',get_the_ID()); ?>";

if ($ori == "Undecided") {
  $style="FFF";
};
```

I keep getting an error saying the variable is undefined but I do not understand why? What am I doing wrong here? How do I set the variable correctly? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What happens when you change to `style="color:<?php echo '#fff'; ?>"`

Comment: You define $style only when $ori is equal to "Undecided". You could define $style = '000' before that condition or check if variable exists with isset() function.

Comment: When I add style="color:<?php echo '#fff'; ?>" the font changes to white as it should

Comment: I defined $style="000" but how would I do the isset() function to check the variable if the "<?php echo get_field('orientation',get_the_ID()); ?>" code I am using does not seem to be working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by updating the code to look like this:

```
<?php 
    $ori = get_field('orientation',get_the_ID());
                                            
    if ($ori == "Undecided") {
    $style="FFF";
};
?>
```

The problem was the <?php echo portion in the variable because I copied it from another field and I was already writing in PHP so I had to remove that section and it worked.